# Azure Mobile Services authentication with WinJS

Tags: winjs, azure-mobile-services

I started a Universal app with WinJS 2.0 for a Windows (and Phone) 8.1 project, and went through the tutorial to register my app for authentication and configure Mobile Services with the Client ID and Client secret. But now how do I actually handle a login with a Microsoft account on my application? I can't find any examples of how to do this anywhere...am I missing something?

I know Mobile Services is working on my application because I am able to do an insertion into a table with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your client object, call:

```
client.login('microsoftaccount').done(function (result) {
  // handle successful login
}, function (error) {
  // handle failed login
});
```

Comment: When I call that code, I get this message in my output:
"JavaScript runtime error: Not implemented"
Any idea why?

Comment: I figured it out: when I start the project as a Windows 8.1 app (instead of phone), it works fine. I guess the phone version really isn't implemented yet.