# How to Authenticate Windows Phone 8.1 JavaScript app with Windows Azure Mobile Services

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 JavaScript Universal App that I want to authenticate with my Azure Mobile Services account. I can successfully make authenticated calls to my service in the Windows Store App but when I call the client.login method, it returns a "Not Implemented" error.

This SO thread indicates that it's not supported:
[Azure Mobile Services authentication with WinJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317700/azure-mobile-services-authentication-with-winjs)

If the login method truly isn't supported in Windows Phone 8.1 JavaScript, how do I make authenticated calls to my service? Do I need to use the Windows Live SDK to get the token, and login with that?

An example would be great! Thanks.